# With ack (or something similar), how do I exclude sub-directories

Tags: search, ack

For example:

```
-- /
---- foo
------ exclude-me
----  bar
------ exclude-me
---- baz
------ exclude-me
```

How could I search all `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, BUT exclude any sub-directory with `exclude-me`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ack, you use case is covered with `--ignore-dir=exclude-me` (excluding by plain directory name only).

For something similar, I would try some similar approach after [browsing](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ack) some manual for some time.

Comment: Oh. I thought it would only exclude `./exclude-me`. Thanks!

Comment: If you're ever wondering what `ack` is searching, drop the search term and add `-f`, and you'll get a list of every file that it selects for searching.  So you can just try `ack --exclude-me -f` and check behavior.